# Devise: Unknown action, Could not find devise mapping for path "/accounts/sign_out"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I keep getting this error every time I point my browser to "account/sign_out" (GET request):

```
Unknown action, Could not find devise mapping for path "/accounts/sign_out"
```

Here's my route for devise:

```
devise_for :accounts, :controllers => { :registrations => :accounts  }
```

It must be something trivial, but I don't get it. Documentation says devise already provides an action for signing out and binds it to this exact route "/accounts/sign_out". Please share with me what am I doing wrong?

The output of `rake routes` shows that the action is mapped:

```
destroy_account_session GET   /accounts/sign_out(.:format)   {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
```

Comment: show the output of `rake routes`, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that in routes.rb I also had `resources :accounts` route declared before `devise_for`. Therefore, the solution turned out to be to put it after the `devise_for` declaration:

```
devise_for :accounts, :controllers => { :registrations => :accounts  }
resources :accounts
```